# Extract text between two strings

Tags: regex, r, text, text-mining, text-analysis

How can I extract text between two strings.

For e.g.:

```
x <- "ABCDName:Mr.Praveen KumarDOB"
```

I want to extract `Mr. Praveen Kumar`.

Also, I want to extract string from starting till it encounters Name:.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-in-r-according-to-a-pattern

Comment: Maybe `strsplit(x, "Name:|DOB")`?

Comment: This seems very similar to [your other question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513552/splitting-strings-in-r/31514980#31514980).

Comment: yes...i m trying to find out various methods to do this as my file is very big

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gsub('^[^:]+:|[A-Z]{1,}$', '', x)
#[1] "Mr.Praveen Kumar"

sub('Name.*', '', x)
#[1] "ABCD"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(x, perl("Name:\\K.*?(?=[A-Z]{2,})"))
[1] "Mr.Praveen Kumar"
> str_extract_all(x, perl("Name:\\K.*?(?=[A-Z]{2,})|.*?(?=Name:)"))[[1]]
[1] "ABCD"             "Mr.Praveen Kumar"
```

Comment: Error : perl is deprecated. Please use regexp instead

Comment: @BitanshuDas In the new stringr, there is no need to wrap with `perl`.  Just use without that wrapping and it should work fine.  `str_extract_all(x, "Name:\\K.*?(?=[A-Z]{2,})|.*?(?=Name:)")[[1]]` works fine for me